# Python бот в дискорде

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord.py

Как сделать так что-бы при реакции на сообщение выдавалась роль при помощи @bot.event? только пожалуйста не пишите написать код который выдаёт роль при реакции на сообщение при помощи @bot.event или что-то подобное.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде так. Можно доп.проверки поставить по типу member.id или message.id, это в кратце. Могу ошибаться, просто в комментарии киньте ошибку, давно не работал с этим эвентом.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == ID:
        member = payload.member
        guild = bot.get_guild(guildID)
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=roleID)
        emoji=payload.emoji
        if emoji.name == 'reactionName':
            member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Corrygan вот ошибка:  
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\1\Desktop\Python\discord\дискорд(эмоджи роли).py", line 10, in on_raw_reaction_add
    channel = payload.channel
AttributeError: 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'channel'

Comment: как я понял  в if channel.id id канала где реакция находиться, в переменной role id=id роли а в if reaction.name == '' всё верно?  потому, что у меня только базовые эмоджи без имени и ещё спасибо что ответили а то уже устал информацию искать

Comment: Я немного ошибся, сейчас отредакьирую код

Comment: хорошо готов сколько угодно ждать

Comment: ошибки нет но роль не выдаётся

Comment: проверь, все ли ты заменил в коде по типу roleID, guildID и т.д.

Comment: on_raw_reaction_add(payload):   В конце строки добавь двоеточие, если не будет работать, то отредактируй свой пост и добавь туда код

Comment: в guildID вводить id сервера? а про : я и так заметил

Comment: Да, guild.id это ид сервера

Comment: `import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 970677750002221086:
        member = payload.member
        guild = bot.get_guild(id=901197387077390386)
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=902953653168660480)
        emoji=payload.emoji
        if emoji.name == '':
            member.add_roles(role)

bot.run('token')`

Answer (score 0):

Если используешь emoji.name, то вводи название эмодзи, в таоем случае нужно:

```
if emoji == :
```

И перед async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload); должна быть строка @bot.event

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136088/discussion-on-answer-by-corrygan-python---).

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 970677750002221086:
        member = payload.member
        guild = bot.get_guild(901197387077390386)
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=902953653168660480)
        emoji=payload.emoji
        print(1)
        if emoji.name == 'video_game':
            member.add_roles(role)
            print(1)
        else:
            print('ошибка')
bot.run('token')
```